# Number of bits in a CDMA system given its Processing Gain

Tags: cdma

A CDMA system is capable of operating with three different processing gains $G_p$: 16, 32, and 64. It is known that when $G_p=32$, the number of bits per slot is 64.

Can we assume that the product of $G_p$ and the number of bits per slot is constant? I've completely lost my track with CDMA, and I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: That should directly be a function of chips per symbol, and no, their product should not be constant – processing gain would be strictly monotonous to number of chips.

Comment: Exactly, Gp stands for processing gain. In some literature it is referred like Spreading Factor and is defined like Gp=T bit / T chip. Hope it helps!